# Fetch Google Maps api in PHP

Tags: php, json, api, decode

I've never been confident with API.
I managed to get API in a webpage using jQuery but I'd now need to decode location lat and lng ONLY of the following json (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=via%20pascal%2033/2%2042123%20reggio%20emilia&key=) using PHP and retrieving the two data as vars:

```
{
"results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "2",
           "short_name" : "2",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Via Blaise Pascal",
           "short_name" : "Via Blaise Pascal",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Reggio Emilia",
           "short_name" : "Reggio Emilia",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Reggio nell'Emilia",
           "short_name" : "Reggio nell'Emilia",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Provincia di Reggio Emilia",
           "short_name" : "RE",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Emilia-Romagna",
           "short_name" : "Emilia-Romagna",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Italia",
           "short_name" : "IT",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "42123",
           "short_name" : "42123",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Via Blaise Pascal, 2, 42123 Reggio Emilia RE, 
Italia",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 44.6666003,
           "lng" : 10.5960504
        },
        "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 44.6679492802915,
              "lng" : 10.5973993802915
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 44.6652513197085,
              "lng" : 10.5947014197085
           }
        }
     },
     "partial_match" : true,
     "place_id" : "ChIJWaiGeqUcgEcR9l6qwloEWgo",
     "types" : [ "street_address" ]
  }
],
"status" : "OK"
}
```

At the end, what I need, is to be able to display to user:

"Latitude is $lat and longitude is $lng"

Thanks

Comment: I've never heard the term "API decoding" before. If you are asking how to decode JSON in PHP the answer is [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode).

Comment: Yea that is what I mean, and I've tried using json decode but I couldn't solve my issue, I'm stacked in decoding just lat e lng, so just json_decode($datalink) isn't fine for me. By the way, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Decoding JSON is a must and if you don't use `json_decode()` you'll have to find a [third-party JSON decoder](https://packagist.org/?query=decode&tags=json) or roll your own.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code if You need only last result point.

```
$myJsonData = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=via%20pascal%2033/2%2042123%20reggio%20emilia&key=");
$myArrayData = json_decode($myJsonData, 1);
foreach($myArrayData['results'] as $myItem){    
$lat = $myItem['geometry']['location']['lat'];
$lng = $myItem['geometry']['location']['lng'];
}
printf("Latitude is %s and longitude is %s", $lat, $lng);
```

Comment: That's just perfect! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your welcome. If you need lat/lng of all results, just collect lat/lng to Array in foreach. Good luck!